# Why isn't heigh:auto working for site container

Tags: html, css, height

I have been developing a site using absolute height values and was curious as to why `height:auto` isn't working for me, can anyone shred some light on this.

HTML Structure

```
<div id="site-content">
<div id="menuconatiner"></div>
<div id="review-container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#site-content{
webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 938px;
padding-bottom:20px;
background-color:white;}

#menuconatiner{
margin:5px;
float:left;
width:190px;}
```

Comment: Without some html and css,how can we know.

Comment: -1; please post some code

Comment: You were initially referring to the `reviews-content` div but it is changed now. If they are the same then it is because both its child elements are floated. Try removing the `float: left` on `review-container` and `height: auto` will work as you expect. (Note: Not added this as an answer because the `div` that was originally mentioned has been modified)

Comment: Thanks harry, will give it a shot. Dooknon and Sharath I posted a link to the page... There's too much html and css to post here, especially as i don't know directly where the conflict is coming from so i can't isolate the code...

Comment: Harry found the problem, Thanks a lot Harry. :) Could i just add a div after reviews-container like this - <div style="clear:left;"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my earlier comment in the OP, the issue is because both the child elements of the `div` are floated. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow. Since the parent isn't containing the child elements, the `height: auto` wouldn't work (actually, will work but would have no effect).

**Option 1:** Remove the `float: left` on "review-container" and `height: auto` will work as you expect, but this has some implications as mentioned in JrnDel's comment.

**Option 2 (Best):** You could add a clearfix div as mentioned in both your own comment in OP and by JrnDel in the comment for this answer.

Comment: Removing the float attribute isn't good. This will cause the element to ignore margins, etc... Instead you should use a clearfix on your floating elements to prevent it, as I explained in my awnser.

Comment: Great. I'm just pointing it out so other people with the same problem know how to fix it.

Comment: @JrnDel: Everybody is learning mate, so no issues pointing out better solutions :) +1 to your solution from me.

Comment: Thanks guys, very detailed responses from both of you !

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS and you wont need the height attribute anymore.

```
#reviews-content {
  display: table;
}
```

The reason why your div isn't auto expanding in height is because it contains floating elements, but you're not using a clearfix. This might be useful links:

- [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)
- http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

My solution above might solve your problem now, but I suggest using a clearfix in the future.